# logging from service objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

In rails, how can I log from a service object used by both my controllers and workers ?
Should I use `Rails.logger` ? `Sidekiq.logger` ?
How should they be configured ?

```rb
# jobs/calculate_distances_job.rb
class CalculateDistancesJob < ApplicationJob


  def perform(home)
    distance = DistanceCalculator.new.calculate home, from: :shore_line
  end

end
```

```rb
# controllers/homes_controller.rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController


  def create
    ...
    distance = DistanceCalculator.new.distance_of @home, from: :shore_line
  end

end
```

```rb
# services/distance_calculator.rb
class DistanceCalculator

  def distance_of(args)
     ...
  rescue 
      Rails.logger.warn "an error occured"
  end

end
```